# Get full name of a method in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

When reading up on how to do specific tasks, I come across things like this:

```
$acl = get-acl somedirectory
$acl.access
```

How do you find the full name of the "access" method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this what you want.

```
$acl | get-member
```

Answer (score 0):

Below should do your work

```
F:\Temp> get-acl | gm
TypeName: System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity

Name                       MemberType     Definition
----                       ----------     ----------
Access                     CodeProperty   System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRuleCollection Access{get=GetAccess;}
CentralAccessPolicyId      CodeProperty   System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier CentralAccessPolicyId{get=GetCentralAccessPolicyId;}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get just the type, I prefer:

```
$acl.GetType().FullName
```

Because objects that have a ton of methods tend to scroll the screen if you just pipe it to `Get-Member`.  Then a web search for the full type name will get you the .Net reference for the class.